# Preserve folder structure upon web site file/folder upload

Tags: python, flask, dropzone.js

I've been looking for a way to preserve the folder structure from the user's local machine when they drop a folder into a Flask website file upload using such as Dropzone or similar. Does anybody have a solution for this? Preferably with Flask / Python / Dropzone, but if not then anything that works will do :-).

Comment: Preserving folder structure involves, you mentioning the path for the file required. Dropzone allows you to iterate the entries, you can catch the names and then submit to Flask, with file content. Create the folders and files with python logic.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, that's what I thought as well, but the object returned from the 'request.files['file']' call only contains the file name and extension, not the path on the users local machine. I've looked around for other ways to get hold of the path information but no luck. Please let me know if you know which command I should use. PS: I have the file and folder creation on the server side working ok, but it's the path information on the client side that I'm trying to get hold of.

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    if(typeof file.fullPath != "undefined"){
        var FullPath = file.fullPath;
     } else  { var FullPath = '';}
        formData.append("original_path", FullPath);
});
```

original_path - passes as an additional parameter in the request the path to the file.

On the server side, you are already working with paths. for example, in php you can do this: and you already write the path $original_path to the database

```
 if($_REQUEST['original_path']!='undefined') {
  $original_path = strip_tags($_REQUEST['original_path']);
  $original_path = htmlspecialchars($original_path);
  $original_path = trim($original_path);
  $original_cl_path = rtrim($original_path, $FileOldName);
  $fullPath = $Directory.rtrim($original_path, "/");
  $folder = substr($fullPath, 0, strrpos($fullPath, "/"));
  if (!is_dir($folder)) {
            $old = umask(0);
            mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
            umask($old);
  }
  } else { $original_path = '';$original_cl_path='';}
```

At least that's how I implemented it. When loading immediately as a folder, everything is written in a structured way to the database